# Linked List: Moving a Node to Start of the Linked List(C++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

The question is to find the key in a linked list and if it is present then move the node containing key to the front

```
struct Node {
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int data, Node *next_node) {
                this->data = data;
                this->next = next_node;
        }
};
```

```
void display(Node *head) {
        Node *temp_head = head;
        while(temp_head != NULL) {
                std::cout << temp_head->data << " ";
                temp_head = temp_head->next;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

```
bool improvedSearch(Node *head, int key) {
        Node *previous = NULL, *current = head;
        while(current != NULL) {
                if(current->data == key) {
                        if(previous == NULL) {
                                return true;
                        }
                        previous->next = current->next;
                        current->next = head;
                        head = current;
                        display(head); /////
                        return true;
                }
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
        }
        return false;
}

int main() {
        Node e(5, NULL);
        Node d(4, &e);
        Node c(3, &d);
        Node b(2, &c);
        Node a(1, &b);
        Node *head = &a;
        improvedSearch(head, 3);
        display(head); /////
        return 0;
}
```

When I call display inside the improvedSearch(head, 3) it shows the output "3 1 2 4 5" but when I call the display inside main function the output is "1 2 4 5". It seems like link to node containing 3 gets lost. Why is this happening?

Comment: That is certainly a C-style linked list. Complete with `NULL` and everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `improvedSearch()`, you are passing in the `head` parameter **by value**, so a *copy* of the caller's `head` is made, and any new value assigned to the `head` parameter by `improvedSearch()` will be only to that copy and not reflected back to the caller.  But, `improvedSearch()` still modifies the contents of the list, and upon exit the caller's `head` is still pointing at the old head node which is no longer the new head node, which is why it appears a node was lost.

To fix this, pass in the `head` parameter **by reference** instead:

`bool improvedSearch(Node* &head, int key)`