# Binary tree: root remains NULL after addition

Tags: c++, binary-tree

The problem is my root stays `NULL` when I need it to change after the first call of my `addContact` function.

I have tried pointer to pointer but got an access error... **This** 0x28... Is all I remember about the error. I have also tried using *& in the parameter of my addContact function but to no avail. What I will show in code is what I thought would fix it but my logic is flawed obviously. Any help would be much appreciated!

This is in my header file.

```
struct Transaction {
    std::string ID;
    std::string lName;
    std::string fName;
    std::string pNum;
    std::string eMail;
    std::string address[7];
};

struct Node {
    Transaction data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node* addHelper(Transaction data) {
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

Node* addContact(Node* root, Transaction data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Checking to see if root stays NULL" << std::endl;
        root = addHelper(data);
    }
    else if (data.lName <= root->data.lName) {
        root->left = addContact(root->left, data);
    }
    else {
        root->right = addContact(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}
```

This is in my Main file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    ifstream file; file.open("bt.txt");
    Transaction inputArray[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        file >> inputArray[i].ID >> inputArray[i].lName >> inputArray[i].fName >> inputArray[i].pNum >> inputArray[i].eMail;
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            file >> inputArray[i].address[j];
        }
    }
    
    Node* root = NULL;
    root = addContact(root, inputArray[0]);
    root = addContact(root, inputArray[1]);
    root = addContact(root, inputArray[2]);
}
```

Comment: Recommendation: Lose the file. Hard code the inputs. This makes your example program easier to use.

Comment: the pointer is a local variable of addContact - modifying it in the function doesn't change it in main

Comment: C++ note: rather than initialization functions like `addHelper`, use constructors.

Comment: Very similar problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74306531/) that I posted an answer for earlier this morning.

Comment: @user4581301 I totally forgot to change it for this post, the actual homework asks for it haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `addContact` you have modified the `root` parameter, but that is local to the function and has no bearing on the value passed in.

Sticking with raw pointers, you may want to pass in a pointer to a pointer, so you can modify the pointer you're pointing to.

```
Node* addContact(Node** root, Transaction data) {
    if (*root == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Checking to see if root stays NULL" << std::endl;
        *root = addHelper(data);
    }
    else if (data.lName <= (*root)->data.lName) {
        (*root)->left = addContact(&(*root)->left, data);
    }
    else {
        (*root)->right = addContact(&(*root)->right, data);
    }

    return *root;
}
```

As noted in comments, you can make `addHelper` a constructor for `Node`.

```
struct Node {
    Transaction data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(Transaction data) : data(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }
};
```

Comment: I attempted a pointer to pointer and it looked similar to your answer... The thing I did different was the recursion of the addContact. I edited my code to look like yours and I am still printing three "checking to see if root stays NULL". I am checking to see if I missed something.

Comment: No it works, haha, The recursion is printing when the left/right are null. Thank you for your answer!